# Regex for parsing some medical data

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been looking for a few hours how to do this particular regular expression magic with little to no luck.

I have been playing around with parsing some of my own medical data (why not?) which unfortunately comes in the form of a very unstructured text document with no tags (XML or HTML).

Specifically, as a prototype, I only want to match what my LDL delta (cholesterol change) is as a percentage.

In the form it shows up in a few different ways:

```
LDL change since last visit: 10%
```

or

```
LDL change since last visit:
10%
```

or

```
LDL change since last visit:

10%
```

I have been trying to do this in JavaScript using the native RegExp engine for a few hours (more than I want to admit) with little success. I am by no means a RegExp expert but I have been looking at an expression like such:

```
(?<=LDL change since last visit)*(0*(100\.00|[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{0,2})%)
```

Which I know does not work in JS because the lack support for `?<=`. I tested these in Ruby but even then they were not successful. Could anybody work me through some ways of doing this?

EDIT:

Since this particular metric shows up a few times in different areas, I would like the regex to match them all and have them be accessible in multiple groups. Say matching group 0 corresponds to the Lipid Profile section and matching group 1 corresponds to the Summary.

```
Lipid profile
...
LDL change since last visit:

10%
...

Summary of Important Metrics
...
LDL change since last visit: 10%
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lookbehind solution is complicated because most languages only support fixed or finite length lookbehind assertions. Therefore it's easier to use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead. (Also, the `*` quantifier after the lookbehind that you used makes no sense).

And since you don't really need to validate the number (right?), I would simply do

```
regexp = /LDL change since last visit:\s*([\d.]+)%/
match = regexp.match(subject)
if match
    match = match[1]
else
    match = nil
end
```

If you expect multiple matches per string, use `.scan()`:

```
subject.scan(/LDL change since last visit:\s*([\d.]+)%/)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change that regexp into getting every instance in the document of "LDL change"? Some of these show them in multiple places for different things. So I want to group them depending on the heading.